# jQuery loop while updating HTML with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, delay

What I'm trying to do is to iterate over an array of values and show it on HTML. And repeat it all over again. It should have 1 second interval in updating the HTML.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wuf25fj8/)

So far, this is what I've tried and it seems that my setInterval does not work well?
Thanks.

```
<div class='x'>Hello World</div>

var arr = [
    'lorem ipsum',
    'dolor sit amet',
    'abc def ghij klmn?',
    'esprit d corps'
];

if (arr) {
    $.each(arr, function (i, v) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var index = i == arr.length - 1 ? 0 : i;
            var data = arr[index];

            console.log(data);
            $('.x').html(data);
            console.log();
        }, i * 1000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to something like

```
var arr = [
    'lorem ipsum',
    'dolor sit amet',
    'abc def ghij klmn?',
    'esprit d corps'];

if (arr) {
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        i = i == arr.length ? 0 : i;
        var data = arr[i];
        $('.x').html(data);
        i++;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vqdtppp3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

1. Create a global variable to store current index.
2. Call a function to print current index value from array in setInterval

var arr = [
    'lorem ipsum',
    'dolor sit amet',
    'abc def ghij klmn?',
    'esprit d corps'
];

```
 var i = 0;
    if(arr){
    setInterval(function () {
                i = (i == arr.length - 1) ? 0 : i;
                var data = arr[i];
                printValue(data);
                i++;
            }, 1000);
    }

function printValue(str){
 $('.x').html(str);
}
```

And here is working demo on JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wuf25fj8/8/